# Assign Different Tax Class to NOT LOGGED IN Group Based on Store

Tags: ce-1.9.2.2, tax-class

Magento 1.9.2.2

I am looking for a way to apply a different tax class to the NOT LOGGED IN customer group based on the store the user is in.

I have two stores, one for a business located in Nevada and the other for a business located in California. The Nevada store needs to charge tax only to NV residents; the California store only to CA residents.

I have created a customer group for each store which has that state's tax rule applied to it. New accounts are set up with the appropriate customer group and taxation is working on that end.

However, guest checkout is enabled and I cannot get the tax calculation to work properly for the NON LOGGED IN customer group.  This group's tax class is currently set to Retail Customer and the problem I'm running into is one of three options:

1) Both NV and CA residents are charged tax on both stores if I add both states' tax rules.
2) Only NV or CA residents are charged tax on both sites if I add one of the states' tax rules.
3) Nobody is charged tax.

What I'd like to do is automatically set a state-specific tax class to the NOT LOGGED IN customer group based on the store that is being viewed. So when a user visits the CA store and are not logged in, they're automatically using the CA tax class and will be charged tax if they reside in CA; conversely, a visitor to the NV store would automatically use the NV tax class so they're charged tax only if they reside in NV.

Is this possible or is there an easier solution that I'm completely missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with tax group manipulation.

1. Create different tax groups
2. Then assign different tax group for second store/website in each product.

Answer (score 1):

We are with the same problem. We have tested some possibilies. But the solution was the solution that Teja Aaa wrote, **I'm agree with Teja Aaa**.

You must create a diferent product tax, assign to all products in that store. Maybe you need to configure tax_class attribute to website before (not global).

With this, you can have a default tax per each product and a different one per store. That assignment per store to the product is the most important.

Now with this, you can create a tax rule that only matches with this product tax, having a different tax zones with other percent. That's the way to have not logged in customers a diferent tax per store.

I hope I explained well!