# How can I change the NOT LOGGED IN default tax rate depending on the store being viewed?

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, tax-class, taxes

My [previous question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/148485/assign-different-tax-class-to-not-logged-in-group-based-on-store) on this matter has received 0 responses, so I'm trying a different question.

My customer has two stores, selling the same products, but one is located in California and the other in Nevada. The requirement is to allow guest checkout, HOWEVER, the California store should only charge tax to CA residents and the Nevada store should only charge tax to NV residents.

How can I dynamically change the tax class that is assigned to the NOT LOGGED IN customer group, depending on the store being viewed?

I created a customer group specific to each store that is assigned at registration. Each has a tax class and tax rule for the respective state. So the taxation works for registered, logged in users.

I would like to set these tax classes to the NOT LOGGED IN user based on the store ID, URL or some other identifying criteria. Is this possible or do I need to require registration for taxation to work?